# Prove the Reverse-delete algorithm gets a Mimimal Spanning Tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

Could someone prove that the Reverse-delete algorithm generates a Minimal Spanning Tree (MST)? I know that the algorithm is greedy and does the following steps:
1. It first orders the edges in descending order.
2. Deletes the highest weighted node unless it disconnects the graph
3. Repeats step 2 until you get a MST.

I have looked on Wikipedia at the following link, but it does not make sense to me:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse-delete_algorithm

I am just looking for a proof that is clearly proves the algorithm but is simple.

Comment: I think your question is more suitable in [Computer science stack](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) or [Theoretical computer science stack](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: But please, as always, check the Help Center for a Stack Exchange site before posting to make sure your question is on-topic.